# How do I generate an App.net api key

Tags: api, api-key

I have been looking around at the source of many of the [App.net projects springing up](https://github.com/appdotnet/api-spec/wiki/Directory-of-third-party-devs-and-apps) and am looking to fork/play with some of them, but I can't seem to find where to get an API key from. Anybody have a link on how to generate one?

Comment: The app.net platform no longer exists. I suggest closing and possibly deleting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found it in the official docs [here](https://github.com/appdotnet/api-spec/blob/master/auth.md)